# Kinetic install not setting ROS_ environment variables

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've followed the instructions to install Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04, and there were no errors during the install, but the setup scripts aren't setting up the ROS_ environment variables.  (ROS_ROOT, ROS_PACKAGE_PATH).  My setup scripts are in /opt/ros/kinetic.  setup.bash just runs setup.sh, but looking at setup.sh, it doesn't seem to be setting or exporting any ROS_ variables.  There are no errors generated, including nothing about problems with the temp file.  It also looks like it runs *setup_util.py, but I see no mention of any ROS* environment variables in that file either.  The CATKIN_ variables aren't getting set either, but I have catkin installed. I haven't set up any workspaces yet, since I'm trying to get the install right.

It seems like the environment isn't right, but looking at the scripts I don't see any place where the ROS_ variables should be set, so I'm wondering if the docs might be out of sync with Kinetic.  If the docs are correct, could anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244872/kinetic-install-not-setting-ros_-environment-variables/) by [rcrowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/28136/rcrowe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found it.  Yes, I was sourcing the scripts, but I had aliases that were causing problems with the scripts.  Once I moved the line in ~/.bashrc above where I set my aliases, things worked correctly.

It would be good if future versions of the scripts used the "command" syntax to avoid conflicts with aliases.  For example:

```
% command ls -l
```

instead of just:

```
% ls -l
```

---

Originally posted by [rcrowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/28136/rcrowe/) with karma: 16 on 2016-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-03**:
I can't find which component is actually responsible for generating the various `setup` files, but I imagine reporting what you observed and found out would be a valuable bug report. If you would consider reporting it, that'd be very much appreciated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-03**:
Also (and a bit pedantic): in general it's better to update your original question with any new or additional information you might have, instead of posting an answers yourself. In this case it's ok, as you're basically actually answering your own question, but please keep it in mind in the future.

**Comment by [rcrowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/28136/rcrowe/) on 2016-10-03**:
I'd be happy to report it and suggest the fix, but I can't seem to find which organization and repo to report it in.  I've searched for setup.sh and install, but nothing comes up.  Any ideas?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-03**:
If I'm not mistaken, Catkin generates those files ([here](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/kinetic-devel/cmake/templates/setup.bash.in) fi). The correct tracker would then be [ros/catkin/issues](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues).

**Comment by [rcrowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/28136/rcrowe/) on 2016-10-03**:
Thanks, I've submitted the issue:

https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/829

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-04**:
Thanks. From the description/comments on that issue I see you have a rather uncommon alias configured: `.='ls -aF'`. That would certainly make things not work. For now I guess you'll have to use `source`, instead of `.`. I can also understand the hesitation of @Dirk Thomas.